# I want to write a regex to match on a file content for a bank card of exact 16 digit

Tags: regex, ecmascript-5, qregularexpression

The card digit starts with 4366 76

1. TEST- 4366766586957844    -- Matched
2. 4366763534634645 -- Matched
3. 5123975748548665 -- Not Matched
4. 6581436676238965347856 -- Not Matched
5. Test-4366766586957544334235 -- Not Matched

I have written ^4366[s-]{0,2}76[0-9]{10} is not working when the card number is appearing in a string.

Comment: The anchor `^` asserts the start of the string. You could use word boundaries `\b4366[s-]{0,2}76[0-9]{10}\b`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you want :

```
[^\d](4366\d{12})[^\d]
```

test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qBHIRj/4)